# Moq how to do a setup when the item could be any of a type but must have a particular property set

Tags: moq

I'm trying to setup for a method which will run:

```
dataAccess.Setup(x => x.GetCars(It.IsAny<CarFilter>()));
```

Ok, so I'm saying to setup the method `GetCars` when it is passed any object of type `CarFilter`.

I want to make this a little more specific.

I want to make it so it will setup when it is passed any object of type `CarFilter` when the property on `CarFilter` `Color = "Red"`.

Does anybody know how to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up needing:

```
dataAccess.Setup(x => x.GetCars(It.Is<CarFilter>(z => z.Color == "Red")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a condition on the match using It.Is(...)

```
public class Car {
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo {
   void DoIt(Car car);
}


[TestMethod]
public void PassesWhenRed() {

    var mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();

    var redCar = new Car { Color = "Red" };

    mockFoo.Object.DoIt(redCar);
    mockFoo.Verify(mk=>mk.DoIt(It.Is<Car>(car => car.Color == "Red")));   // Passes

}


[TestMethod]
public void FailsWhenNotRed() {

    var mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();

    var blueCar = new Car { Color = "Blue" };

    mockFoo.Object.DoIt(blueCar);
    mockFoo.Verify(mk=>mk.DoIt(It.Is<Car>(car => car.Color == "Red")));  // Fails

}
```